# Will a "rebuild as needed" library be recompiled if I change settings of a project that uses it?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I have a program that uses a library (DPK/visual controls). The library was compiled in Debug mode. Which means that Optimizations is OFF, RangeChecking is ON, etc, etc. The library is set to 'Rebuild as needed'. I do not intend to redistribute it (internal use only).

What happens if I compile my program in 'Release' mode? The code contained in the library will be recompiled automatically to 'Release' mode? Or I have to load the DPK and recompile my library in 'Release' mode first?

---

Update:
Related to 'Rebuild as needed' Embarcadero's help says it all: "Builds the package as needed".
Which I interpret as 'if the program is compiled in Release mode, the library needs to be recompiled so we will do it for you'.
Is my interpretation too... biblical?

---

This experiment shows that (in the conditions described above) the code contained in a library will be compiled into the EXE based on DPR's settings and not on DPK's settings.

The compiler does not care about DPK file when it recompiles its PAS files (applies only when the DPK in not loaded in IDE).**

So here is the (easy to reproduce in all systems) proof:
Let's call my program Prog.DPR (contains Prog.pas) and my library Lib.DPK (contains LibUnit.pas). The library contains TMyPanel visual control. DPR is in Release mode. DPK is in debug mode.

```
I install the library. I exit the library ('Close all').
I load the DPR in IDE, I also load LibUnit (Attention: I load only the unit, not the DPK)
I put TMyPanel on my program's form.
The LibUnit is automatically added to the USES clause on my program.
I edit LibUnit. I compile. It works. New DCU file is generated for LibUnit.
I go to library's folder and I delete the DPK (and the Dproj) but I keep LibUnit.pas.
I edit LibUnit. I compile. Still works! New DCU file is generated for DCU file is generated for LibUnit.!!!!
```

The question is: if there is no info about how LibUnit should be compiled (the PDK was deleted), how was LibUnit compiled????? Obviously the compiler used DPR's settings. Which is 'Release' mode. Which means my library was integrated into the program as 'release'. .

Comment: What is "a VCL"? There is only "the VCL". It's supplied with Delphi and you don't compile it.

Comment: Make sure your debug build uses debug dcu's and your release build doesn't. You do this through the library path (or the project options). As @David says, you don't compile the VCL...

Comment: Yes, you would want to distribute the library build in release mode and not the library build in debug mode.

Comment: @Marjan - so the program will use the library as it is (in Debug mode) without recompile it?

Comment: Yes, I believe that is the case. The program will use the library you give it and thus as you compiled it. `Rebuild as needed` only rebuilds the library its source code was changed, not when any of its "users" changes.

Comment: @Marjan- "only rebuilds the library its source code was changed". I totally agree. This is why I did the experiment above. Which shows that if I edit the library while the DPR is loaded, the compiler won't care about the DPK file!!

Comment: The output of a package rebuild is a new .bpl file. You for sure did not get a new one of those with no dpk file. Most likely you are not actually using the runtime package and the unit is linked directly to your exe. Which is probably the most sensible approach for you in any case.

Answer (score 5):

Switching between debug and release targets in your executable will not lead to any referenced runtime packages being rebuilt.

Packages have their own options that are independent from projects that use them. That's the only possible design choice. Just imagine if you had a package that was used by two other projects, A and B, say. Now, A is built for debug, but B is built for release. The package can't be built for both at the same time.

"Rebuild as needed" means that packages will be re-built if the latest build is out of date with respect to the package's source.

---

Regarding the "experiment" in your question update, it's most likely that your exe is not linking at runtime to the package. Instead the .pas file is being directly compiled and linked as part of your exe project.

Comment: Using whichever settings are specified in the package project file

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. Hard to see how a package could be compiled without reference to its .dpk and .dproj files.

Comment: Naturally it's hard to re-compile a package after you delete all the sources. I can only guess as to what's happening in your experiment. All the same, what I state in the answer is correct.

Comment: We are going round in circles here. You want to use runtime packages but then delete the package source files. That makes no sense. I answered the question that you asked.

Comment: +1 to offset the undeserved downvote. I'm suspecting it was a little revenge thing (see the deleted answer).

Answer (score 0):

This experiment shows that (in the conditions described above) the code contained in a library will be compiled into the EXE based on DPR's settings and not on DPK's settings.

The compiler does not care about DPK file when it recompiles its PAS files (applies only when the DPK in not loaded in IDE).**

So here is the (easy to reproduce in all systems) proof:
Let's call my program Prog.DPR (contains Prog.pas) and my library Lib.DPK (contains LibUnit.pas). The library contains TMyPanel visual control. DPR is in Release mode. DPK is in debug mode.

- I install the library. I exit the library ('Close all').
- I load the DPR in IDE, I also load LibUnit (Attention: I load only the unit, not the DPK)
- I put TMyPanel on my program's form.
- The LibUnit is automatically added to the USES clause on my program.
- I edit LibUnit. I compile. It works. New DCU file is generated for LibUnit.
- I go to library's folder and I delete the DPK (and the Dproj) but I keep LibUnit.pas.
- I edit LibUnit. I compile. Still works! New DCU file is generated for DCU file is generated for LibUnit.!!!!

The question is: if there is no info about how LibUnit should be compiled (the PDK was deleted), how was LibUnit compiled????? Obviously the compiler used DPR's settings. Which is 'Release' mode. Which means my library was integrated into the program as 'release'. .